# New Important Security update & ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 Question

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates, hardware

Couple days ago ubuntu popped up a message window:

```
**New important security and hardware support update.**
WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack ended on 2016-08-04
```

and Second pop up message is that ubuntu recommended me to update 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

The main point of this question is that do I need worry about my hard disk? I mean if I do both of those updates, none of those do not touch my hard disk? So all my important files / project are 100% safe?

I tried find more information and some kind of certitude from Google for this but no luck. So if you can enlightening me it would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can update to Ubuntu 16.04, and your files & data will be kept. (Make sure you have always have a backup of your data though). Updating does modify the contents of your hard disk though, since that's where Ubuntu is installed, but it won't erase your files/

Comment: @JonasCz Thank you for this information, and yes maybe I should make backup of my data just in case. I haven't done that in couple of months.

Comment: It's always good to have a backup anyway just in case, in case of e.g. hardware failure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your information is safe.

The worst case scenario is that the installation process get compromise. If that is the case, no worries. Write back here, we should be able to help. And if you need your files fast, you would be able to boot from a live CD/USB to navigate to your hard disk drive home folder.